# Regex to extract word from last but one

Tags: regex, space

I have a similar string - "Hello my Number is 200 created"

I have to extract the number 200, I tried  \bis([\s\S]+$), but it is pulling 200 created

Appreciate you help in this regard

Comment: Use `\bis\s+(\S+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Lb6CA/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expression

```
\w+(?=\W+\w+\W*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/28MBwu/1/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\w+    # match 1+ word chars
(?=    # begin a positive lookahead
  \W+  # match 1+ non-word chars (spaces, punctuation, etc.)
  \w+  # match 1+ word chars (last word in string)
  \W*  # match 0+ non-word chars (spaces, punctuation, etc.)
  $    # match end of string
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```js
const str = 'Hello my Number is 200 created'
const regex = /(\S+)\s\S+$/
const word = str.match(regex)[1]
console.log(word)
```

No need for regular expressions by the way, for some this could be more readable

```js
const str = 'Hello my Number is 200 created'
const words = str.split(' ')
const word = words[words.length-2]
console.log(word)
```